# Why ElasticSearch Java Client index Future completes before the record is searchable?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic4s

I'm using [elastic4s](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s) client that returns a `Future` in response to index request and when that future completes I still have to do `Thread.sleep(1000)` before I can query for that indexed record. Mostly it is exactly 1 second. Is there an elasticsearch setting that I can change so that when the Future completes the record will be available?

I tried to use the java client directly `client.prepareIndex....execute().actionGet();` and it ends up exactly the same way, I have to call `Thread.sleep(1000)`

Is there any settings I can change for the record to be ready after the future completes?

```
execute(index into(foo, bar) id uuid fields baz).await
Thread.sleep(1000) // This is mandatory for search to find it
execute {search in foo}.await // returns empty without Thread.sleep(1000)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you may be having to wait for the default index refresh interval to come into play before you can query the newly indexed data. [The refresh interval is 1 second by default](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html#bulk) and can be changed with the following

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/_settings -d '{
    "index" : {
        "refresh_interval" : "1s"
    } }'
```

Alternatively, you can refresh the *shard* after the indexing operation by [including the `refresh` parameter in the query string of the index operation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-refresh). This may be more useful than changing the refresh interval globally

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/{index}/{type}/{id}?refresh=true' -d '{
  "property" : "value"
}'
```

Comment: Note, if you are going to do a lot of inserts/updates/deletes, doing a refresh after each operation slows down the complete process.

Answer (score 0):

Russ's answer is correct, but I want to add a bit more about the Scala side.

When you do an index operation, the `future` returned is completed as soon as the Elasticsearch cluster has processed the command. That is not the same  time as when the document is available to search. That is, as Russ pointed out, 1 second later (by default).

So your future completes at k. Your document is available at k+1sec.

You can adjust the refresh interval when creating the index, eg in Elastic4s

`create index "myindex" refreshInterval "200ms" mappings ...`

In the next release you can use Scala durations eg

`create index "myindex" refreshInterval 200.millis mappings ...`

But be aware, by adjusting this too much you remove some of the optimizations that the refresh interval brings. If you are doing multiple indexes, etc then look at the bulk api. (In Elastic4s just wrap your calls in `bulk(seq)`)